# Yeoman generator for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I'm starting learning angularJS and find out yeoman is quite useful. But some how the controller/service/model generated by yeoman is not good for minifying later. Because due to what I see through the generated [template](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/templates/javascript/service/service.js) (service in this case ) we have to inject the service implicitly.

But if we want to minify later, it's recommended to inject explicitly using $inject.

So my question is : Is it correct that what I understand ? If it's not then what is the correct way to inject with generated template from yeoman.

Otherwise, we shouldn't use generated template from yeoman at the moment if we want to do minify later, right ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Yeoman Angular generators with the --minsafe, for example:

```
yo angular:controller user --minsafe
```

check other options here:
https://npmjs.org/package/generator-angular

Edit:
A follow up on this. It's now unnecessary to use the --minsafe flag, as yeoman comes with the ngmin app, which automatically converts all applicable code to be *minifiable*, and then minifies it :)

Answer (score 5):

so yeoman gives you something like this when generating a service

```
testApp.factory('Thing', function(dep1, dep2) {
  return {/*...*/};
});
```

This is problematic when the code is minified, because the process of minification shortens function parameters, and angular uses them to infer which dependencies to inject.

To inject dependencies I recommend the inline annotation which looks like this

```
testApp.factory('Thing', ['dep1', 'dep2', function(dep1, dep2) {
  return {/*...*/};
}]);
```

Notice the second argument is an array that lists the proper dependency names and that its final item is a function where such dependencies will be injected.

---

Edit: The Angular generators for Yeoman now support minification for both JavaScript and CoffeeScript code with the `--minsafe` flag as shown by @Ramiro